# How to improve Windows Aero desktop performance?

Tags: windows-7, hardware-rec, aero, windows-experience-index

Why is my desktop graphic performance less and gaming graphic performance high, as they both depend on same graphics card?

What can I do to improve Windows Aero desktop performance?

Comment: What is your Video Card ?

Comment: @Michael B: GeForce 8400. Not a perfect vga, but I don't think that justifies that I have more gaming power than desktop power...

Comment: Personnaly I have 6.9 for both with a 8800GT

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a year old, but for future referece it's recommended you update your graphics drivers; this should bring the *"Desktop performance for Windows Aero"* up to the same level as your *"Gaming graphics"*.

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually have any problems with the windows aero desktop? If so, please list those. If not, I wouldn't worry about trying to make a silly number bigger for no other reason besides the number.

Comment: I want to understand the logic behind my desktop gets a lower score than gaming...

Comment: It's Microsoft...sometimes logic doesn't apply.